# Java collapsible if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, pmd

I use [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net) to check my code. It gives me very useful hints in most cases, but I can't figure out what could be improved in the following scenario.

The original code looks something like this:

```
if ((getSomething() != null && getSomethingElse() != null)
     || (getSomething() == null && getSomethingElse() == null))
{
   ...
}
```

PMD tells me:

> Sometimes two 'if' statements can be consolidated by separating their
>   conditions with a boolean short-circuit operator.

For simplicity, let's just use a and b as boolean variables. Then this piece of code looks like this:

```
if ((!a && !b) || (a && b))
```

This can be transformed to one of the following:

```
if ((!a || b) && (a || !b))
if (!(a^b))
```

and finally

```
if (a==b)
```

So I simplified my code to

```
if ((getSomething() == null) == (getSomethingElse() == null))
```

However, PMD keeps complaining (in fact about all three versions). Is this a false positive or is there a better way of writing the if-condition?

Comment: Are you sure there is not another _if_ statement in your code? PMD complains about _two_ if statements, not about one being more complex than necessary

Comment: I can't think of a way to better your final version (that's what I'd code). What's *inside* the `if` block - is there another `if` in there?

Comment: I just discovered the `@javax.annotations.Nonnull` and `@javax.annotations.Nullable` annotations in the `JSR305` specifications. The implementation I am using is the Google one in `com.google.code.findbugs:1.3.9`. It has clean up my code considerably, and Intellij IDEA auto generates code and warnings based on these annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was something different. The if-statement was the only code inside another if (the code comes from a validation-method):

```
if (...)
{
   ...
}
else if (...)
{
   ...
}
else if (...)
{
   if ((getSomething() == null) == (getSomethingElse() == null))
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

What the PMD-message means, is that I could combine the conditions of the last else-if and the inner if-clause:

```
if (...)
{
   ...
}
else if (...)
{
   ...
}
else if (... && ((getSomething() == null) == (getSomethingElse() == null)))
{
      ...
}
```

However, I'm not sure, if I'll do this, because the original version seems much clearer to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((a != null) && (b != null) && (a==b))
```

..although personally, I'd do the null checking prior to this if statement so I could handle the a == null and b == null cases individually

Comment: this is a great suggestion about handling the `null` cases individually. that way you can throw specific NPE that tell the user exactly which one was `null` or handle them in a specific way.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `|| (a==b)`?

Comment: @Gandalf  I don't think so....  Since the JRE processes if statements left to right looking for logical true or false, the if statement i posted would evaluate like so:

1) Is 'a' not null?  True, move to the right.  If false, the entire evaluation cannot be true, so stop evaluating.
2) Is 'b' not null?  True, move to the right.  If false, the entire evaluation cannot be true, so stop evaluating.
3) Now that we know that 'a' and 'b' are both not null, we can safely evaluate 'a==b'

Comment: @claymore1977 Yes I understand your statement and how it evaluates but it does not do what the original statement did. In the original statement a and b are not compared for equality and the original yields true if both are null.

Comment: @Gandalf:  Excellent point sir!  I got too deep in the methodology and lost sight of intent :)

Comment: a and b are boolean expressions. They are either true or false, not null.

Comment: @Martin: Right on.  I was taking Boolean objects into account.  I suppose a tad more context and a bit less abstraction would have been a bit helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that large blocks of conditionals are difficult to reason about.

OTOH, not every warning PMD emits needs to be paid attention to--consider the ROI. Is it worth refactoring or restructuring to make it cleaner? Can the same functionality be handled in a different way?

If it's not worth it, don't bother.

Comment: I don't think I'll change my code, but it was still interesting to find out, what could be "improved".

Comment: It always is, even if we hear the advice and promptly ignore it ;)